# Increasing Performance of a Database Fetch Operation in

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using stored procedures to fetch information from the database. First I fetch all the parent elements and hold them in the array and then using the parent Id I fetch all the related children. Each parent can have 150 children. There are about 100 parent elements. What is the best way to increase the performance of the fetch operation. Currently it takes 13 seconds to retrieve.

Here is the basic algorithm:

```
while(reader.read()) 
{
    Parent p = new Parent(); 
    // assign properties to the parent 

    p.Children = GetChildrenByParentId(parent.Id);    
}
```

Comment: Does GetChildrenByParentId() create another connection and call another stored proc?

Comment: Yes it create a separate connection and calls a separate stored procedure

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should get all that data in one SQL select / stored proc (do some sort of join on child data) and then populate parent and children objects. Now you have 100*150 = 15000 requests on DB and I if you can do this with one request I would expect dramatic performance effect.

As Brian mentioned it in comment, that is known as RBAR, RowByAgonizingRow :) 
Like a achronime a lot, here is more :

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/

Comment: I guess I can try that! Thanks

Comment: +1 Antonio. This is what is known as RBAR (google it). The relational database is designed to retrieve sets. This code could be compared to going to the bank and withdrawing $1 1000 times (1000 transactions!) instead of withdrawing $1000 with 1 transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The first and most important step is to measure the performance.  Is it SQL Server that is the bottle neck, or .NET?

Also, you need to minimize the times you have to go back to the database, so if you can retrieve all of the data you need in a single stored procedure, that would be best.

From your question, it sounds to me like it is SQL Server that is the problem.  To test this, run your stored procedure from SQL Query Anylizer, and see how long it takes for a known parent id.  I bet you just need some indexes added to your underlying table to make it possible for SQL to get the data faster.  If possible, look at your Execution Plan for the stored procedure.  You can find a good article about reading execution plans [here](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Examining_Query_Execution_Plans).

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2008 is easy, create a user defined table type and pass the list of parent IDs to that, OR you can just use the logic you used to get those parent IDs in the first place and just join to the tables that hold child data.

To create the table type, you make something like this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Int32List]
AS TABLE (
[ID] int NOT NULL
);
GO
```

And your stored proc goes something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProc]
@ParentIDTable [dbo].[Int32List] READONLY
AS
--logic goes here
GO
```

And you call that procedure from your C# code like this:

```
DataTable ParentIDs = new DataTable();
ParentIDs.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionInfo);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProc", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add("@ParentIDTable", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = ParentIDs;
command.Parameters["@ParentIDTable"].TypeName = "Int32List";
```

This way is nice, because it's a great way to effectively pass a list of values to SQL Server and treat it like a table. I use table types all over my applications where I want to pass an array of values to a stored proc. Just remember that the column names in the C# DataTable need to match the column names in the table type you created, and the TypeName property needs to match the table type's name.

With this method, you will only make 1 call to the DB, and when you iterate through the results, you should also make sure to include the ParentID in the select list so you can match each child to the proper parent object.

Here's a great resource to explain table types in more detail: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html